# Returning File Pointer in Golang

Tags: pointers, go

I'm still struggling with the basics of Golang.

Consider the following sample code:

```
func OpenOutputFile(name string) (fp *os.File) {
  fp, err := os.Create(name)
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }

  defer func() {
      if err := fp.Close(); err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
  }()

  return fp
}
```

I would assume that calling:

```
fp := OpenOutputFile("output.txt")
```

would now make `fp` a file pointer (`*os.File`), so that I could call a statement like:

```
io.WriteString(fp, "Hello World")
```

In another function. But when calling this method, the error is generated:

```
0 write output.txt: bad file descriptor
```

So it appears that the pointer returned is not valid. How can I return a properly formed pointer to use with `io.WriteString`?

I appreciate the help!

Of note: Everything executes as intended when the creation of the file pointer and the writing to the file pointer exists in the same method. Breaking the logic into a function causes it to not behave as intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
>
> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to
>   the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the
>   surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of
>   its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is
>   panicking.
>
> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and
>   parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the
>   actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are
>   invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the
>   reverse order they were deferred. If a deferred function value
>   evaluates to nil, execution panics when the function is invoked, not
>   when the "defer" statement is executed.
>
> For instance, if the deferred function is a function literal and the
>   surrounding function has named result parameters that are in scope
>   within the literal, the deferred function may access and modify the
>   result parameters before they are returned. If the deferred function
>   has any return values, they are discarded when the function completes.

```
func OpenOutputFile(name string) (fp *os.File) {
    fp, err := os.Create(name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := fp.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    return fp
}
```

You open the file

```
fp, err := os.Create(name)
```

You close the file

```
err := fp.Close()
```

After the `Close`, `fp` no longer points to a valid file descriptor.

Comment: Ahhh I don't know why I didn't think of that sooner. I thought `defer()` was called on error or something. Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to name the return value. The variable fp you create there is shadowed by the variable fp you create when you call `fp, err := os.Create(name)`

Comment: @user1431317: Your claim that `fp, err := os.Create(name)` creates a  variable `fp` is false. [Short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations): Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

Comment: You're right, because they're in the same block. But you still don't need to name it.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the close function and deferring it in higher scope worked for me. I don't know if this is a good practice in Go though. It relies on closing/deferring outside of original function:

```golang
func OpenFileFromArgs() (*os.File, func()) {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        panic("input file not provided")
    }

    inputFilePath := os.Args[1]
    stat, err := os.Stat(inputFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("file %s doens't exist", inputFilePath))
        } else {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("error: %v", err))
        }
    }
    if stat.IsDir() {
        panic("provided path is a directory")
    }

    inputFile, err := os.Open(inputFilePath)
    closeFn := func() {
        err := inputFile.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic("failed to close input file")
        }
    }

    return inputFile, closeFn
```

and then in the higher scope:

```golang
    inputFile, closeFn := library.OpenFileFromArgs()
    defer closeFn()
```

Confirmed using step by step debugger - at program end, the deferred close function is correctly called and file descriptor closed.